# How can I improve the performance and the readability of my function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I recently had to do a test for a job interview, and the prompt was to code a function that returns the closest number to 0 given an array of negative and positive numbers.

My function works correctly but I heard back from the recruiter saying that my function is not very performant and and that the readability was not great, here are the problem that they mentioned:

- Performances à double check (filter + sort + for + push + reserve + shift, 4 identical call to  Math.abs)
- Lack of readability  ( 4 if / else if)

I would like to know how I could have improved my function to make it more performant and more readable?

here's my function:

```
const closestToZero = (arr) => {
  // 1-a variables:
  let positiveNumbers = [];
  let negativeNumbers = [];

  // 1-b returns 0 if the input is either undefined or an empty array
  if(typeof(arr) === 'undefined' || arr.length === 0) {
    return 0
  }

  // 2- filter out non-number values then sort the array
  const onlyNumbers = arr.filter(item => typeof(item) === 'number').sort((a,b) => a-b);

  // 3- split the numbers into positive numbers and negative numbers
  for(let i = 0; i < onlyNumbers.length; i++) {
    if(onlyNumbers[i] > 0) {
      positiveNumbers.push(onlyNumbers[i])
    } else if (onlyNumbers[i] < 0) {
      negativeNumbers.push(onlyNumbers[i])
    }
  }

  // 4- reverse the negative array to get the closest to 0 at the first index
  let reversedNegativeArray = negativeNumbers.reverse()

  // 5- get rid of all the other values and keep only the closest to 0, if array empty return 0
  let closestPositiveNumber = positiveNumbers.length > 0 ? positiveNumbers.shift() : 0
  let closestNegativeNumber = reversedNegativeArray.length > 0 ? reversedNegativeArray.shift() : 0

  // 6- Compare the result of the substraction of the closestPositiveNumber and the closestNegativeNumber to find the closestToZero
  if(closestPositiveNumber - Math.abs(closestNegativeNumber) > 0 && closestNegativeNumber === 0 ) {
    return closestPositiveNumber
  } else if (closestPositiveNumber - Math.abs(closestNegativeNumber) < 0 && closestPositiveNumber === 0) {
    return closestNegativeNumber
  } else if(closestPositiveNumber - Math.abs(closestNegativeNumber) > 0) {
    return closestNegativeNumber
  } else if (closestPositiveNumber - Math.abs(closestNegativeNumber) <= 0) {
    return closestPositiveNumber
  }
}
```

requirements:

- if the closest number in input could be either negative or positive, the function returns the positive one
- if the input array is undefined or empty, the function returns 0

**when input is [8, 5, 10] the function returns 5**

**when input is [5, 4, -9, 6, -10, -1, 8] the function returns -1**

**when input is [8, 2, 3, -2] the functions return 2**

Comment: This would probably be a better fit for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ since your code works.

Comment: @Turnip ok thank you, I'll transfer it there

Comment: Please read their [help section](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help) before posting. I am not very familiar with their rules.

Comment: That's a really complicated way you've chosen (and parts are unnecessary unless you've missed to add requirements like "ignore non-numeric input values"). Just loop over the input array and get the difference between zero and the current value. Keep the one with the smallest "distance"

Comment: `arr.reduce((result, current) => Math.abs(current) < result ? current : result, Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER)`

Comment: `(x && x.length) ? Math.min(...x.map(n => Math.abs(n) || Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER)) : 0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function is indeed very complicated. You can make good use of the `Math.abs` function here to clean things up quite a bit. Here is a js implementation that I would have given

```
test = [-1, 5, 4, -9, 6, -10, -1, 8, 1]; 


function closeToZero(arr){

    if(typeof(arr) === 'undefined' || arr.length === 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    ret = test[0]; 

    for(i = 1; i < test.length; i++){
        if(Math.abs(ret) >= Math.abs(test[i]) ){
            if(Math.abs(ret) == Math.abs(test[i])){
               ret = Math.max(ret, test[i]);
            }else{
                ret = test[i];
            }
        }
    }
    return ret; 

}

print(closeToZero(test));
```

Optionally you can also check for bad input if that was required

Comment: I did not add all the requirements in the question : if the closest number in input could be either negative or positive, the function returns the positive one .... 
if the input array is undefined or empty, the function returns 0

Comment: @AziCode I updated the code to meet the new requirements

Comment: at the beginning I wanted to use a for loop, but then I figured that if I found the 2 closest numbers to 0 (negative and positive) side, I could get rid of the rest of the numbers

My thought process was that with huge arrays, with my technique I wouldn't have to loop over all the numbers, since I would find the 2 closest numbers to 0

Comment: @AziCode to find the two closest numbers to zero, you still need to loop over the whole array, both of our solutions are `O(N)`. Mine is actually better since it uses `O(1)` space where yours uses `O(N)` space.

Comment: yes you are correct, I actually added more unnecessary steps

Comment: @AziCode dont feel too bad, there have been quite a number of interviews now where I choke on the obvious answer, looking for that silver bullet can really mess with your head. Good luck on the next one!

Answer (score 0):

Although this isn't the best StackExchange forum for an "answer," Andreas does in fact give one.  A solution might be like this: *(pseudocode)*

```
winner = 0      # arbitrarily assume the zeroth element is closest
for (i from 1 to array-length):
   if abs(array[i]) < abs(array[winner]):    # this one's closer ...
      winner = i
```

The `abs()` *(absolute value)* function is, of course, an indicator of "how close the number is to zero."  `abs(-3) == 3` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

There's a possibility that the recruiter would have found a solution that uses `reduce` also unreadable.

But to extend on Andreas comment.

Here's an example snippet with a function that uses reduce, comparing the absolute values or the sign.

```js
const closestToZero = (arr) => {
    if(!arr || arr.length === 0) return 0;
    return arr.reduce((acc, x) =>  (Math.abs(x) < Math.abs(acc) || (Math.abs(x) === Math.abs(acc) && x > acc)) ? x : acc);
}

console.log(closestToZero());
console.log(closestToZero([]));
console.log(closestToZero([8,5,10]));
console.log(closestToZero([5, 4, -9, 6, -10, -1, 8]));
console.log(closestToZero([8, -2, 3, 2]));
```